# How to set custom authentication cookies?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm building a custom ASP.NET Identity 2.0 implementation that uses our own data model, another ORM, other business logic, etc. By default, a user is logged in by setting the `ApplicationCookie`, after which the `AuthorizeAttribute` recognizes the cookie and logs the user in. For our own implementation, I  want to add more ways to log in. For example:

- Impersonation
- Password reset token
- Google Authenticator (two-factor)
- SMS (two-factor)

In all these scenarios the user must be logged in, **but** what actions the user is allowed to perform depends on the way he logged in. For example: when the user logged in using a 'password reset token', he may change his password but not do anything else. When the user logged in with 'username + password', he may do basically everything, except for the actions that need a higher permission level (where the two-factor methods come in play). In order to do this, I want to build a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` that checks what login method was used, and then decides whether the user may perform the action or not.

The problem I'm facing is that I can set other cookies than `ApplicationCookie` (e.g. the `TwoFactorCookie` that is being set by going through the SMS process), but those cookies are not recognized as authentication cookies. Thus, when I have a `TwoFactorCookie`, I can't use that cookie to log in. Only having an `ApplicationCookie` results in a log in.

The issues I'm struggling with:

- Do I always need to use `ApplicationCookie` to log in or can I use custom cookies to log in as well (so for example I can log in using `ApplicationCookie`, `TwoFactorCookie` and `XYZCookie`?
- Should I have different cookies for each authentication method or should I have only 1 cookie and store the authentication method/type in a different way (for example in a Claim)?
- If I should use different cookies, should I also write custom authentication middleware for each authentication method/type or can I use the default `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware`? As far as I know, the only thing that has to be done is set a cookie, and flag it with the correct authentication method so I can see how the user was logged in.

**Edit:**

As per Hao Kung's suggestion I made a couple of extension methods that look like this:

```
public static void UseSmsSignInCookie(this IAppBuilder app, TimeSpan expires)
{
    if (app == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("app");

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = ApplicationAuthenticationTypes.Sms,
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        CookieName = CookiePrefix + ApplicationAuthenticationTypes.Sms,
        ExpireTimeSpan = expires,
    });
}
```

I try to log someone in by calling `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` with a custom `ClaimsIdentity` that has my custom AuthenticationType (SMS). This doesn't work though: after calling SignIn, the result of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.AuthenticationType` still equals `ApplicationCookie`. The cookie has been set as expected though.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

So each instance of a CookieMiddleware basically represents one auth cookie, if you want multiple cookies, you can add more than one CookieMiddleware and to retrieve the ClaimsIdentity mapping to your cookie, you just need to call Authenticate on the AuthenticationManager passing in the AuthenticationType for the cookie you want.

Comment: So you're saying is that I should just reuse `CookieAuthenticationMiddleware` with a different `CookieAuthenticationOptions` object (that has a different `authentication type`? I tried that today but it didn't work, but I'll try again tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Oh, another question: what's the purpose of the `TwoFactorCookie` and the `ExternalCookie`? They are being set but they don't seem to do much, I can't use them to log in.

Comment: The external cookie is used to store data from social logins, the two factor stuff is used to store state for two factor auth, pretty much exactly what you are asking for :)

Comment: I made a custom AppBuilder extension that calls `app.UseCookieAuthentication` with a `CookieAuthenticationOptions` object with my custom `AuthenticationType`, `AuthenticationMode` = Passive and a custom `CookieName`. When I call `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` with the custom `AuthenticationType` the cookie is set correctly, but `AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync` still returns null for the `AuthenticationType`. What am I missing?